# What kind of objects can be elements in a Spark RDD?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

What are the constraints on the elements that can be passed to `SparkContext.parallelize` to create an RDD? More specifically, if I create a custom class in Python, what methods do I need to implement to ensure it works correctly in an RDD? I'm assuming it needs to implement `__eq__` and `__hash__` and be picklable. What else? Links to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated. I couldn't find this anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking the only hard requirement is that class is serializable (picklable) although it is not necessary for objects which life cycle is limited to a single task (are neither shuffled nor collected / parallelized).

Consistent `__hash__` and `__eq__` is required only if class will be used as a shuffle key, either directly (as a key in `byKey` operations) or indirectly (for example for `distinct` or `cache`).

Additionally class definition has to be importable on each worker node, so module has to be already present on the `PYTHONPATH`, or distributed with `pyFiles`. If class depends on native dependencies, these have to be present on each worker node as well.

Finally for sorting types has to be orderable using standard Python semantics.

To summarize:

- No special requirements, other than being importable:

  ```
  class Foo:
     ...

  # objects are used locally inside a single task
  rdd.map(lambda i: Foo(i)).map(lambda foo: foo.get(i))
  ```
- Has to be serializable:

  ```
  # Has to be pickled to be distributed 
  sc.parallelize([Foo(1), Foo(2)])

  # Has to be pickled to be persisted
  sc.range(10).map(lambda i: Foo(i)).cache()

  # Has to be pickled to be fetched to the driver
  sc.range(10).map(lambda i: Foo(i)).collect()  # take, first, etc.
  ```
- Has to be `Hashable`:

  ```
  # Explicitly used as a shuffle key
  sc.range(10).map(lambda i: (Foo(i), 1)).reduceByKey(add)  # *byKey

  # Implicitly used as a shuffle kye
  sc.range(10).map(lambda i: Foo(i)).distinct  # subtract, etc.
  ```

Additionally all variables passed with closure have to be serializable.